# How to use ComboBox without Selecting items when down/up arrow is pressed? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a list of items which gets filtered as soon as the user types in the combobox. So if the user presses down arrow then the first item gets selected and the list is filtered again so it remains the last selected item available in the list.

I don't want the items to be selected unless enter key is pressed. Same like a mouse hovering and clicking on an item to select it.

EDIT: My question still remain Unanswered by our VBA Experts.

EDIT_2: I am still searching for the solution. I have tried different ways to achieve this, still something seems wrong. Could anyone look into the code I have provided.

Here's my code which i tried but it Failed:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Abort As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
        .ListRows = "5"
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 3
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        'Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If

End Sub

 Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode


        Case 38  'Up
            If TempCombo.ListIndex <= 0 Then KeyCode = 0 'ignore "Up" press if already on the first selection, or if not on a selection
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection past the first entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListIndex - 1

            End If
            Me.TempCombo.DropDown

        Case 40 'Down
            If TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListCount - 1 Then KeyCode = 0
        ' This method was from the discussion I linked, prevents "falling off the bottom of the list"
            Abort = True
            If Not KeyCode = 0 Then ' If on a selection before the last entry
                KeyCode = 0
            'Manually choose next entry, cancel key press
                TempCombo.ListIndex = TempCombo.ListIndex + 1

            End If
            Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End Select
    Abort = False

End Sub

Private Sub TempCombo_Change()
    If Abort Then Exit Sub ' Stop Event code if flag set
    Abort = True
    ' sets the flag until finished with commands to prevent changes made by code triggering the event multiple times

        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13

        'Start
        If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("N8")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.OnKey "~", ActiveSheet.Range("P9").Select
        Application.OnKey "~"
        ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("P9")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.OnKey "~", ActiveSheet.Range("N11").Select
                Application.OnKey "~"

        End If
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown

    ' ~~~ Insert Code you want to run for other cases here ~~~

    Abort = False
End Sub
```